# How to add two moments?

Tags: momentjs

There is two moment variables :

```
var m1 = moment("00:30:10", "hh:mm:ss") , m2 = moment("00:05:40", "hh:mm:ss");
```

How to add these two moment variables so that I get something like `00:35:50` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like what you want to do is to sum **[durations](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/)**. Like this:

```js
d1 = moment.duration("00:30:10")
d2 = moment.duration("00:05:40")

// this will change the value of d1 "in place"
d1.add(d2)

formatted = moment.utc(d1.asMilliseconds()).format("HH:mm:ss") 

console.log('The formatted time is:', formatted); // "00:35:50"
console.log('The "humanized" value is:', d1.humanize()) // 36 minutes
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```